# Server not responding in intervals

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I've been running my server (**Ubuntu 16.04**) for years without any issues what so ever and just this week, my websites has gotten really slow every now and then, to a point where the server don't even respond sometimes.

First I thought it was something wrong with Apache, but some people has been saying that they got problem connecting to Teamspeak as well.

I never had connections issues before, so therefore I got very little experience when it comes to this and I'm not quite sure which logs to provide.

I haven't changed anything on the server recently, the problem just appeared.

I don't see any suspicious users or user groups and I'm running CloudFlare if that's any help.

Internet works just fine on every other machine in the household.

Comment: Check that your disk space is not full.  If `no disk space left' up will slow down your server. Delete unnecessary log that's over 1G if necessary you may back up your log externally.

Comment: `/dev/sda1      111156008  63324260  42162272  61% /`  I'm at 61%, shouldn't be enough to make it slow I guess?

Comment: Post result of `mtr -rc5 your-server-ip-here`

Comment: Here. If I manage to format it right.. Can't get 4 spaces to work.

    `HOST: domain.com       Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst 
    StDev
    1.|-- c<MYIP>.bredband.  0.0%     5    5.0   3.3   1.3   7.4   2.8`

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: In short: My websites (Running Nginx + Apache thru VestaCP) has become insanely slow out of nowhere. Every now and then they don't even respond, which gives me that CloudFlare page which tells you the host is offline. Everything else on the network is working perfectly fine. I've even ran a full system check using HP's (All hardware passed) tool and reinstalled the server entirely by now, including changed network port on the computer (Got 2). Still the same problem.

Comment: I'm so sorry that you're going through this: to my understanding, Nginx is your front, passing data to Apache (backend) controlled by VestaCP?  To properly diagnose it, don't ignore any little thing. Start back from the Cloudflare, make sure that you don't have ***double A record*** set. If your Nginx is doing reverse proxy ( passing request to apache ) make sure that you add Cloudfare Header in config.  Use `tcpdump` to make sure that request are getting to your Host from ***Cloudflare***

Comment: I don't have double A records, I think. Is that two of the same or the one called "AAAA"? I'm unfortunately no DNS wizard. I haven't made any changes to my DNS records and it's been running fine for over 3 years. VestaCP is indeed using Nginx as reverse proxy tho.

Comment: What is output of `dig youdomain.com` ?

Comment: Seriously can't figure out how code blocks works on this page. I made a pastebin instead because it was too long to fit into a comment. https://pastebin.com/Evwx7zji

Comment: I ran test on both domain that's your pastebin, the first one redirected me to suspended page and the second to a wordpress page.

Comment: I haven't setup the suspended one, it'll just show a "Powered by" page if I un-suspend it. The other one I just dropped a WP install on for the moment for testing purpose, trying to figure this one out.